# Power Query How to Assign Values to range of Numbers

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a range of numbers that I need to assign scores to and would like to see if there's an easy way to do it through Power Query:

```
   >150 = 0,
101-150 = 1,
 51-100 = 2,
  21-50 = 3,
   <=20 = 4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way is just an `if .. then .. else if ..` construction as a new custom column similar to this:

```
Score =
if [value] > 150 then 0
else if [value] >= 101 and [value] <= 150 then 1
else if ...
else if [value] <= 20 then 4
else null
```